# Order list by month and hour in R

Tags: r

I have a list of file names I want to read into R. Currently, the file names are in a character vector in alphabetical order so when I use the vector to read in the files, they are arranged in a list in alphabetical order. What I would like is to arrange the character vector according to month and hour (which are contained in the file names in an uncommon format, and there are no date/time variables in the data files themselves). My vector looks something like

```
chr [1:288] "tair_apr_01.txt" "tair_apr_02.txt" ... "tair_oct_24.txt"
```

That is, there is an element for every hour of every month (the data are averaged across every day, so there are 288 elements in my vector).

Is there a way to reorder my vector so that it's listed by month? i.e.

```
chr [1:288] "tair_jan_01.txt" ... "tair_dec_24.txt"
```

I know how to sort/order when there are numeric values, and I've seen ways to order by date as long as it's in a certain format. No command I know is able to be applied to this situation, so maybe what I'm really looking for is an efficient way to manually sort the 288 elements. Here's a smaller, complete example:

What I have is

```
filelist <- c('tair_apr_12.txt', 'tair_dec_24.txt', 'tair_jan_01.txt')
```

and what I want is

```
filelist <- c('tair_jan_01.txt', 'tair_apr_12.txt', 'tair_dec_24.txt')
```

Comment: Is the full list of 288 consistent? That is, are the three "pieces" always separated by an underscore?

Comment: The structure of `filelist` isn't really clear. Could you have for instance `"tair_apr_84.txt"` - i.e. the 84th hour of April?

Comment: The answers below worked, but yes, each file has a consistent name of the form 'tair_[month]_[hr].txt'. As for the `filelist`, the range of hours is from 01 to 24. The data were originally gathered every hour of every day of every month, but then everything was averaged across the entire month by hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert to a date and then order. Note that I'm using days instead of hours since you have one with a 24 for the hour, and the `%H` decimal format should be 00-23 not 00-24 or 01-24 or something.

```
filelist <- c('tair_apr_12.txt', 'tair_dec_24.txt', 'tair_jan_01.txt')
gsub('.*_([a-z]+)_(\\d{2}).*', '\\1\\2', filelist)
# [1] "apr12" "dec24" "jan01"


o <- order(strptime(gsub('.*_([a-z]+)_(\\d{2}).*', '\\1\\2', filelist), '%b%d'))
filelist[o]
# [1] "tair_jan_01.txt" "tair_apr_12.txt" "tair_dec_24.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dplyr answer

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr)

data_frame(file = filelist) %>%
  separate(file, c("tair", 
                   "month", 
                   "day",
                   "extension"),
           remove = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(date = 
           month %>%
           paste(day) %>%
           strptime("%b %d") %>%
           as.POSIXct) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  use_series(file)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using @rawr's `filelist`:

```
filelist[order(strptime(paste0("01_",filelist), "%d_tair_%b_%H"))]
#[1] "tair_jan_01.txt" "tair_apr_12.txt" "tair_dec_24.txt"
```

All this does is assign an arbitrary 1st day of the month `"01"` to the start of each timestamp, and then uses this to ensure a full date format can be generated.

You can use `%H` safely for finding the order of `01-24` hours, as opposed to `00-23`, as according to `?strptime`:

> ‘%H’ Hours as decimal number (00-23).  As a special exception strings
>   such as ‘24:00:00’ are accepted for input, since ISO 8601 allows these